# ¿Cómo covertir una alert en un campo de texto en Javascript?

Tags: php, javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Suma</title>
<link rel="stylesheet"  href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!--Optional theme-->
<!--<link rel="stylesheet"  href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com /bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">-->
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid"> 
<form action="examen.php" method="post" name="calculadora">
<label><h3>Agregar Valores</h3></label><br>
<input type="text" id="numero1" name="c1"/><br><br>
<input type="text" id="numero2" name="c2"/><br><br>
<button class="btn btn-danger"  onclick="alert(suma(10,50))">Sumar</button><br><br>
<input type="text" placeholder="Resultado" id="" name="resultado"/
<br><br> 
</div>   
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var suma = function (numero1, numero2) {
  var numero1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("numero1").value);
  var numero2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("numero2").value);
  var resultado = numero1 + numero2;

  return resultado;
  }

 </script>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Espero que sea lo que necesités.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Suma</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!--Optional theme-->
    <!--<link rel="stylesheet"  href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com /bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">-->
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Descomentá el el comentario de form para probar que te funcione, si te funciona ya ves como enviar la petición a examen.php -->
        <!-- <form action="examen.php" method="post" name="calculadora"> -->
        <label>
            <h3>Agregar Valores</h3>
        </label><br>
        <input type="text" id="numero1" class="form-control" name="c1" /><br><br>
        <input type="text" id="numero2" class="form-control" name="c2" /><br><br>
        <button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="suma();">Sumar</button><br><br>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Resultado" id="resultado" name="resultado" class="form-control" readonly />
        <br><br>
        <!-- </form> -->
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    // La función no necesita parámetros porque los vas a obtener por medio de javascript (document.getElementById)
        suma = function () {
            // Cuando sean variables locales de una función o fragmento de código regularmente se usa let en vez de var.
            // let es variable local, var es global
            let numero1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("numero1").value);
            let numero2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("numero2").value);
            let resultado = numero1 + numero2;
            // Acá realizamos el set para el input resultado
            document.getElementById("resultado").value = resultado
        }

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

yo creo lo que buscas es algo así:

```
var suma = function (numero1, numero2) { 
var numero1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("numero1").value); 
var numero2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("numero2").value); 
var resultado = numero1 + numero2;

    return resultado; }

//mensaje

alert("La suma es:"+suma(23,54));
```

Comment: No se sabe si es peor la pregunta o la respuesta.